# How to filter array of date onClick outside map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm finally starting to understand how to pass and retrieve data using React. But I have one problem, I have this click handler `this.SortASC` when I click on the title I would like to sort titles based on alphabetic order.

I'm struggling to get this to work.. any idea how i can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { getMovies } from '../services/fakeMovieService';

class Movies extends Component {
    state = {
        movies: getMovies(),
    };

    handleDelete = movie => {
        const updateMovies = this.state.movies.filter(m => m._id !== movie._id); // Display all movies but not the one selected.
        this.setState({
            movies: updateMovies,
        });
    };

    SortASC = () => {
        console.log('Sorted');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {this.state.movies.length > 0 ? (
                    <div className="m-2">
                        <p>
                            Showing {this.state.movies.length} in the database.
                        </p>
                        <table className="table table-striped table-dark">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" onClick={this.SortASC}>
                                        Title
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col">Genre</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Stock</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Rate</th>
                                    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {this.state.movies.map(movie => {
                                    const {
                                        _id,
                                        title,
                                        genre,
                                        numberInStock,
                                        dailyRentalRate,
                                    } = movie;

                                    return (
                                        <tr key={_id}>
                                            <th>{title}</th>
                                            <td>{genre.name}</td>
                                            <td>{numberInStock}</td>
                                            <td>{dailyRentalRate}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button
                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                        this.handleDelete(movie)
                                                    }
                                                    className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                                    Delete
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    );
                                })}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <h4 className="m-4">
                        There are no movies in the database.
                    </h4>
                )}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Movies;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: NVM I think the edit made is easier to understand

Comment: You will want to use this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: can you please show what the data looks like in your state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just sort the `movies` array in state in `SortASC`.

Like this:

```
SortASC = () => {
    const { movies } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        movies: movies.sort((a, b) => a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1)
    })
};
```

And if you want to sort descending, you can swap the `1` and `-1`.

Comment: God bless you, my friend. Works like a charm, one more question, how can i revert my action after the second click?

Comment: This solution destroys the original order, so you could keep the original movies unchanged but then also have a `displayMovies` array in state, which would actually be rendered. So to reset you would need also a variable to check if the order is currently sorted and if so then copy original `movies` into `displayMovies` otherwise copy `movies.sort` into `displayMovies` but that's getting a bit complicated maybe. Perhaps a better way to do it is just offer other ways to sort the movies instead of an undo (e.g. alphabeticalDesc, numberInStock).

Comment: You are right! Keep it like this, i will create multiple filters for Genre and title rating and stock! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you want something like: `arr.sort((titleA, titleB) => titleA - titleB)`

although it can get a little more complex (checking for same/duplicate titles, etc)